# Recursive data type java generic type warnings

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a recursive HashMap data structure as such:

`public HashMap<Character, HashMap> root;`

The `HashMap`s inside of root are also of type `<Character, HashMap>`. This throws raw type warnings because the HashMap inside is not parametrized. I can't think of a way to do away with these warnings, because any attempts to explicitly parametrize a `HashMap` will not stop because of its recursive nature. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you can't. What will the inner-inner `HashMap` have?

Comment: What is the value type of the `HashMap`s inside the `HashMap` of `HashMap`s?  Somewhere the chain must stop at a non-generic class.

Comment: It is a good thing that you see this issue when defining your generic types here. Something is bound to go wrong if you cannot conclude a definitive generic type.

Comment: The end is `new HashMap<Character, HashMap>(0)`

Comment: Can you also give a concrete use case of this kind of map? Then we can fully assess if your question is reasonable.

Comment: I'm making a trie. The end of a word is an escape character and an empty HashMap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare:

```
class MyHashMap extends HashMap<Character, MyHashMap> { }
```

Define:

```
MyHashMap root;
```

### Generalized form:

Declare interface:

```
interface RecursiveMap<K> extends Map<K, RecursiveMap<K>> { }
```

Declare implementations:

```
class RecursiveHashMap<K> extends HashMap<K, RecursiveMap<K>> implements RecursiveMap<K> { }

class RecursiveTreeMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, RecursiveMap<K>> implements RecursiveMap<K> { }
```

Define:

```
RecursiveMap<Character> root  = new RecursiveHashMap<Character>();

RecursiveMap<Character> root2 = new RecursiveTreeMap<Character>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It you are not sure about generic type of inner `Map` then use below code.

**Always use interfaces for declaration.**

If in future you want to change `root` of type `TreeMap` then you can do it easily.

```
Map<Character, Map<Character,Object>> root=new  HashMap<Character, Map<Character,Object>>();
```

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of generics. I mean you still have it from `Map<Character, Map>` at the start, but you are throwing them away after that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Please can you explain more about *but you are throwing them away after that.*

Comment: You are using an `Object` as a generic type parameter... That alone should say enough as `Object` is a raw type.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got it but at least we can ensure `key` of type `Character`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be wisable to have recursive Map because at any given point of time , you might want to have some kind of object type different than the Map, or else it would be of infinte depth (making no sense). 
Try using:

1. `Map<Character, Map<Character, Object>`, OR
2. Use a Class to hold a Map and Recursively store the class.